# Disk Storage - I believe my HDD still has Windows' remnants (I want them out)

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

So, I have been messing with a spare HDD I have lately. I realized that, for some reason, I have a /dev/sda1/ .fat32 partition, which is flagged as boot, on my HDD. I previously worked with Windows. I thought I had removed everything as I started my enterprise on changing distros. I searched quite a lot, and perhaps I have used the wrong keywords, or searched for the wrong questions, to no avail. I hope someone can help me.

1. Why does my HDD still have a 512 MiB partition, which is flagged as boot (even though Gparted displays it as totally unused), formatted in the .fat32 filesystem? I thought it was exclusive to Windows, as I changed all partitions to .ext4
2. Can I safely delete this partition?
3. I haven't allocated a swap partition, yet everything has running smoothly. Is it begginers' luck?

I sincerely hope I was able to convey my questions - English is not my first language and it has been some time since I last spoke it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lASds.png)

Comment: Ubuntu uses swap file instead of swap partition nowadays. Do not delete the small 512 MB partition, it contains your bootloader.

Comment: @mook765, thank you. I thought so - but the fact that intrigues me is its type of filesystem. Shouldn't it be .ext4?

Comment: No fat32 is beautiful. This partition is needed for UEFI boot and must be formatted with a fat file system, everthing is good.

Comment: @mook765, thanks a lot mate!